# Null output from data object in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-props

I am attempting to have the console log the data from entering city and country into a textInput with react-native using the Open Weather Maps API. Whenever I enter a city and country into the fields I get 'no city 404'. However, if I hard code one into where the string for const city and const country are, I get my desired return. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've attempted several different methods and googled till my eyes turned red, but I'm stuck. I know the API and everything works cause I'm able to hard code the stuff. It's something in my Form.JS is what I speculate.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

This is my App.js file

```
//import a library to help create a component
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';

//import components
import Header from './src/components/Header';
import Form from './src/components/Form';
import Weather from './src/components/Weather';

//API KEY from Open Weather Maps
const API_KEY = 'cad2d6dddccc9804f43e7c3af9e56f52';
const city = '';
const country = '';

export default class App extends Component {

  getWeather = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const api_call = await 
  fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather? 
  q=${city},${country}&appid=${API_KEY}&units=metric`);
  const data = await api_call.json();
  console.log(data);
}

render() {
return (
    <View >
      <Header headerText='Weather Fetcher' />
      <Form
      getWeather={this.getWeather}
      city={this.city}
      country={this.country}
      />
      <Weather />
    </View>

  );
 }
}
```

This is my Form.js file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 
'react-native';

export default class Form extends Component {

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.viewPut}>
    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>City</Text>
    <TextInput
    style={styles.textInput}
    value={this.city}        
    />

    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Country</Text>
    <TextInput
    style={styles.textInput}
    value={this.country}
    />
    <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={this.props.getWeather}
    >
     <Text> Fetch My Weather </Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>

);
}
}
```

[The App I'm Making](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szzrn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have an event sleep function for TextInput and manage its value in component state. That’s how you should deal with textfields in React

Take a look at corrected Form component code

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
   import { TextInput, View, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

   export default class Form extends Component {
       constructor(props){
          super(props);
          this.state={
            city: '',
            country:''
          }
       }

       handleCity = event => {
          this.setState({
               city: event.target.value
          })
      }

      handleCountry = event => {
          this.setState({
             country: event.target.value
          })
      }
     render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.viewPut}>
             <Text style={styles.textStyle}>City</Text>
             <TextInput
                style={styles.textInput}
                value={this.state.city} 
                onChange={this.handleCity}       
             />

           <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Country</Text>
          <TextInput
             style={styles.textInput}
             value={this.state.country}
            onChange={this.handleCountry}
          />
        <TouchableOpacity
           onPress={this.props.getWeather}
         >
          <Text> Fetch My Weather </Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>

   );
   }
   }
```

Also you should move getWeather function from App to Form component as it doesn’t make sense to have it in app component. Because getWeather functionality is not used in App component so I would recommend you to move that function Form component and do the setState to city and country values and play with text fields

Comment: @Marsel Gray you are welcome. Can you accept and upvote the answer so that it will help future readers

Answer (score 0):

Firstly don't do something like this

```
const city = '';
const country = '';
```

You can simply use state variables like this

```
constructor(props){
   super(props)

   this.state = {
     city: '',
     country: '',
   }
}
```

Then use TextInput like this

```
         <TextInput
            {...this.props}
            ref={comp => (this.input = comp)}
            style={[styles.valueText]}
            value={this.state.country}
            onChangeText={value => this.setState({country: value})} />
```